# Import current price from website to spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importxml, importhtml

As you can probably gather from the title, the goal is to plug the current price of this product into a spreadsheet.
Perhaps I'm over-complicating things, but there must be an easy way to do this.

The route I've taken is to utilize the IMPORT XML feature on GoogleSheets. I feel like I'm probably encountering a syntax error, I just can't seem to get it right.
My cell currently looks like:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552", "id('WM_PRICE')/x:div/x:div/x:span/x:span[2]")
```

I used an extension for Firefox called Xpath checker to pull the Xpath of the pricing element from the website, but the application doesn't seem to approve. Unfortunately I couldn't find much documentation on using GoogleSheets in this manner (as a 'simple' scraping tool).

## UPDATE

Tried IMPORTHTML; it appears that the site has the price nested between lines 18 and 19. So using the following does not work:

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552", "list", 18)
```

I know the unique selector for the node containing price is

```
#WM_PRICE > div:nth-child(1)
```

Is there not some way to just use this to syndicate the information on Google Sheets?

## RESOLUTION

Okay, I've found a semi-solution by utilizing the IMPORTHTML function as a table and then parsing the data and chopping it down to what I need. There's probably a better way.
My solution:

```
=MID(Query(IMPORTHTML("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552", "table", 2), "SELECT Col1 LIMIT 1"),8,6)
```

By changing the HTTP bit I can now effectively get the price of anything under $99.99 at Walmart.com (EDIT: After some testing, it works on FOOD only, the page layout for other items is different), anything over that and I'll lose a decimal place. Fortunately, there aren't many items I need that will fall into that category.

***Explanation of the formula:***

First was to import the precious data, I achieved the raw import with the following:

```
IMPORTHTML("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552", "table", 2)
```

However, it imported several columns and rows, no bueno. So I chopped them off by "selecting" column 1, and "limiting" the rows to 1.

```
Query((), "SELECT Col1, LIMIT 1")
```

But that left me with a single, mucked up cell: The formula returned the word Online before the $ value (and a bunch of junk after it), so I parsed 8 characters into the string and stopped parsing after 6 characters via the MID command (fortunately there was a single space buffer after the dollar amount).

```
=MID((),8,6)
```

If anyone else has a more elegant way to do this, please still comment. I just wanted to leave some stepping-stones for anyone looking to do something like this in the future.

Comment: Tried everything but can't get it to work. It is known to be [buggy](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/JlqjIzioL7M).

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain. I can't come up with a universal solution either. I just had to "rig" it. But it won't work with anything over $99.99 in value, because it will start cutting off the 6th value (penny decimal place).

Comment: Evidently the solution I came up with only works for food items. Other departments have a different layout, and therefore won't parse correctly.

Comment: That really sucks. You might as well just use a programming language (an actual one) to extract the data you need and then paste it in Google spreadsheet. Is that a possibility or no?

Comment: Actually, I can probably write something in JavaScript and add it as a custom function. Would that be something you're looking for?

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: Edit out your resolution into a new answer below so that it is not mixed in with the question itself

Comment: I added the correct xpath query at the bottom as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error in your importxml was in the xpath syntax. here is the correct one:

```
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552","//*[@itemprop='price'][1]"))
```

edited: added the `[1]` at the end of the xpath to prevent the duplicate price.

Comment: It seems to be duplicating the numbers. Can you fix / update this? PS: Also, would like to be able to do the same with Amazon & NewEgg for some shopping calculations and comparisons.

Comment: @AlexS I fixed it, all it needed was an `[1]` at the end of the xpath to show the price once - also yeah i can do it for the other sites also but I need sample urls

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I can't do it with Google's functions. As a result, I decided to write a custom function.

[image]

Go to **Tools -> Script Editor**. Click **"Spreadsheet"** on the left hand side to create a new document. Scroll down and paste the following code in:

[image]

```
function getWalmartPrice(url) {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); //Can't create document element ^_^
  html = html.substring(html.indexOf("bigPriceText1"));
  html = html.substring(html.indexOf(">") + 1);
  var txt = html.substring(0, html.indexOf("<"));
  //same thing for the small price
  html = html.substring(html.indexOf("smallPriceText1"));
  html = html.substring(html.indexOf(">") + 1);
  return txt + html.substring(0, html.indexOf("<"));
};
```

It was a pain to write (no `XHR`, no `document`, etc.) but it's just a bunch of JavaScript string manipulations to find the DOM elements' contents.

[image]

**Save** the file - click File->Save, control/command-S, or the button presented above. You will probably be prompted with a bunch of permission-related messages, and you'll also have to give the project a name (doesn't matter what you call it, as long as the file is called `Code.gs` which it automatically is). Now you can go back to the spreadsheet and test it out. Remember, the function is `=getWalmartPrice(<url>)`. A tool-tip does not pop-up on custom functions as you write the function's name, hence don't be alarmed when it doesn't show up.

Here's a sample:

[image]

```
=getWalmartPrice("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552")
=getWalmartPrice("http://www.walmart.com/ip/Dell-Pre-Owned-Refurbished-Silver-745-Desktop-PC-with-Intel-Core-2-Duo-Processor-4GB-Memory-750-Hard-Drive-and-Windows-7-Professional-Monitor-Not/21907344")
```

I included the second example to show that the code is universal. It works for products from different departments (i.e. electronics) and for things that cost over $99.99. The code correctly returns `$209.18`.

In case you want a number and not a string, you can pretty easily change the code to extract only the numbers and no string. You can do `txt.match(/\d/g).join("");` to get only numbers out of a string, and of course parse it to do some manipulations.

Comment: Not working anymore. Not sure why. Can you fix / update this? PS: Also, would like to be able to do the same with Amazon & NewEgg for some shopping calculations and comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The following setup returns the price:

A1: `http://www.walmart.com/ip/Morton-Sea-Salt-Fine-Salt-17.6-oz/10849552`
A2: `(//div[@itemprop='price'])[1]`
A3 Formula: `=CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML(A1,A2))`
A3 Result: `$2.35`